# Can the following io module concepts be clarified: blocking vs non-blocking raw-streams and interactive/non-interactive raw-streams?

Tags: python, io

I've been reading through the io module documentation and some of the concepts mentioned in passing are not clear to me. The following passages are taken from the [doc-page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html):

> BufferedIOBase.read(size=-1): If the argument is positive, and the underlying raw stream is **not interactive**, multiple raw reads may be issued to satisfy the byte count (unless EOF is reached first). But for **interactive** raw streams, at most one raw read will be issued, and a short result does not imply that EOF is imminent.

> BufferedIOBase.read: A BlockingIOError is raised if the underlying raw stream is in **non blocking-mode**, and has no data available at the moment.

> BufferedWriter.write(b): When in **non-blocking mode**, a BlockingIOError is raised if the buffer needs to be written out but the raw stream **blocks**.

1. Under what conditions is the raw stream interactive? Examples would be helpful.
2. When is the raw-stream underlying a BufferedIOBase instance in non-blocking mode, and when does it block? Examples would again be helpful.